# Request header field Time-Zone is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, cors

I have a WEB API which I am consuming from POSTMAN, and it works perfectly fine:

Headers:

Content-Type:application/json
X-Developer-Id:asdasdas
X-Api-Key:asdasdas
Authorization:Bearer sasdasdsa
Time-Zone:Morocco Standard Time

When I do a GET request in POSTMAN it works fine, however from angular 2 (Ionic 2) I get the following error:

```
Request header field Time-Zone is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.


let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('date', date);

        //Header
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': AppSettings.ContentType,
            'X-Developer-Id': AppSettings.XDeveloperId,
            'X-Api-Key': AppSettings.XApiKey,
            'Time-Zone': AppSettings.time_zone,
            'Authorization': AppSettings.Authorization + localStorage.getItem("AccessToken")
        });

        var RequestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = {
            url: AppSettings.UrlAvailability + userId,
            method: 'GET',
            search: params,            
            headers: headers,
            body: null
        };

        return this.http.get((AppSettings.UrlAvailability + userId), RequestOptions)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .do(data => { data },
            err => console.log('error: ' + err));
```

First I would think that the API developers have to do something on the server side, like enabling that Time-Zone Header on CORS, however if that would be the case then we would get the same error on POSTMAN, but it works fine there.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you need to configure on the server. You first need to make sure you have CORS support. I don't use ASP.NET, so I don't know how to do it. I'm pretty sure a quick google search will find you the answer. Then you need to make sure in that server CORS config, that special headers you want the client to be able to send are added to the CORS allowed headers. That's what the error is saying: that the headers are not included in the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. The response header would look like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Developer-Id, X-Api-Key, Time-Zone, Authorization
```

To learn more about CORS, see the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

> First I would think that the API developers have to do something on the server side, like enabling that Time-Zone Header on CORS, however if that would be the case then we would get the same error on POSTMAN, but it works fine there

No, Postman does not have the same restrictions. It is a native desktop app. Fun fact: 99% of people who post questions on SO that hava a CORS problem, have somewhere in their post "...but it work with Postman!". So don't feel bad :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove some of your headers and check you content-type so your request could be considered as a "simple request" and then won't trigger a CORS preflight as explained in the doc.

source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#examples_of_access_control_scenarios

> Apart from the headers automatically set by the user agent (for example, Connection, User-Agent, or the other headers defined in the Fetch spec as a forbidden header name), the only headers which are allowed to be manually set are those which the Fetch spec defines as a CORS-safelisted request-header, which are:
>
> 1. Accept
> 2. Accept-Language
> 3. Content-Language
> 4. Content-Type (please note the additional requirements below)